# How can I create a simple server with only 2 clients in C++?

Tags: c++, client

I need to create a server that allow ONE at time client connected.
The rule is that just one client can be connected and if the other one try to connect, can read a messagge like this "another client is connected, do you want disconnect it?".
Then if type yes the client will be disconnected.

My problem is about this step. How can I disconnect a client and connect the other one?
Can someone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: You disconnect a socket by closing it or using the `shutdown` system call. You're already connected to the other client if you managed to send it a message, so your question is unclear. What exactly are you not managing to code?

Answer (score 0):

First build the abstract server structure. So you write a program which accepts TCP connections in one thread and pass them to a worker thread, which can read and send messages.

You should keep one Singleton containing a reference (or pointer, your choice) to the Worker with the currently connected client (or null, if there is noone connected).

To keep it simple, the acceptor thread should create a new Worker thread everytime it accepts a connection, and the Worker thread is terminated, when the connection breaks up.

Now you have to think about a protocol. For this simple task, 5 messages should be enough. Maybe every message ends with an endl, so you can use methods like readline if there is somthing like this in C++.

First, the `CONNECT` message. The server should return `OK` (second message), if noone is connected to it, and `ERROR` (third message), if there is already one connected.

The fourth message is `CONNECTWITHDISCONNECT`, it connects the client to the server and disconnects any other client. The newly connected client should receive a `OK` message from the server, and the disconnected one should receive `DISCONNECT` (fifth message).

Now, you could use the disconnect message also with the client, so one can disconnect, without requiring another to connect.

The client should send a `CONNECT` first, if it receives `ERROR` then, it can ask the user to disconnect the other client, and if the user wants to, the client sends `CONNECTWITHDISCONNECT`.

Comment: Ok very useful answer.
But for thread I have to use fork or pthread?
Which is better for this goal?
Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know much about C++, I'm a Java programmer. But from my knowledge of informatics vokabulary I guess, that pthread is the one you need, because fork remembers me to fork/join, which is a concept for parallelizing large tasks, and has nothing to do with the problems a normal webserver has to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Another option (if you don't want to deal with multiple threads or multiple processes) is to use select() or poll() to handle multiple sockets at the same time within a single thread.  In particular, you can select()-for-read on your accepting socket, and select() will return with that socket marked as ready-for-read whenever another client is trying to connect.  Once you have accept()'d the client, you can pass the client's connection socket (as was returned by accept()) to select()'s read-sockets-set so that you will also be notified whenever the client's socket has bytes ready for you to read.  And so on.

Comment: I have written already my server with some features, and now I use send and recv for the message and fork() for the multiclient.
Anyway, is possible use poll?